Where can I find information about such a relationship about the limits of functions that Wolfram suggests?
Where can I find information about such a relationship about the limits of functions that Wolfram suggests 1? I'm interested about whether it is formal method? And whether exist aritmetic for limits f.e. with ∞(f(x))  which is in Wolfram?

I plugged it in Wolfram Aloha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit+dy%2Fdn+as+n-%3Einfinity&assumption=%22LimitHead%22+-%3E+%7B%22Discrete%22%7D , and it does not show anything. Also, I'm not sure if your dy/dn is a derivative or d is just a normal constant.

You can see it f.e. here link in step by step option. Sorry, I didn't put here link I did not know that I can copy this from wolfram like that.

Intuitively it's saying that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} dy/dn = L \ne 0$ and $|L|<\infty$, then at large $n$, $y$ must behave like $nL$. So the limit of $y$ will be $\pm\infty$, depending on the sign of $L$.

Ok but can I find some books or publications about this thinking processing? Where maybe it is in some formal process with proof? Or it is so fundamental that it shouldn't be explain? And  should I get conclusions from standard students books?
